# exceptions/conditions in classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can you make conditions in classes?

```
tr.list_row2:hover > td > div {
/* proporties */
}
```

How can you make an exception for `tr.list_row2:hover > td > div.test`? The class doesn't have to be added if the element has the class `div.test`

Comment: "The class doesn't have to be added" You mean the *styles* don't have to be added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS3's [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
tr.list_row2:hover > td > div:not(.test) {
}
```

or for old IEs which don't recognize it,

```
tr.list_row2:hover > td > div {
}

tr.list_row2:hover > td > div.test {
    /* undo above rules */
}
```